# Hibernate - Update parent object with onetomany object

Tags: hibernate, merge, one-to-many

Let's consider having such three DTOs.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = true)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable=false)
    private Set<UserElement> userElements;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "element")
public class Element {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = true)
    private Long id;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_element")
public class UserElement {

    public UserElement (User user, Element element) {
        this.user = user;
        this.element = element;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = true)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", updatable = false, insertable = false, nullable=false)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "element_id")
    private Element element;
}
```

Let's assume that in database in table user_element I have currently one row: user_id = 1, element_id = 1;

With given code:

```
List<UserElement> userElements = Lists.newArrayList();
User user = session.get(User.class, 1);
Element element1 = session.get(Element.class, 1);
Element element2 = session.get(Element.class, 2);
userElements.add(new UserElement(user, element1));
userElements.add(new UserElement(user, element2));

user.setUserElements(userElements);
session.merge(user);
```

I was expecting to have in my table two rows:
user_id = 1, element_id = 1 and user_id = 1, element_id = 2, 
but instead I'm getting ConstraintViolationException. What am I doing wrong? Can't I just simply provide collection of userElements?

Comment: And the exception stack trace is...? My guess is that it complains that user_id may not be null. You've told Hibernate not to insert a value in that column.

Comment: Stacktrace says that I cannot have two rows with the same id. Which is clear to me, because I'm trying to add element that has user_id =1 and element_id = 1 and such record already exists. The question is how to save such collections? Do I always have to delete redundant rows before merging parent object?